# Microsoft Web Deploy fails trying to delete folder

Tags: msbuild, continuous-integration, msdeploy, web-deployment-project

I'm deploying a application in one of my continuous integration steps.

I use rake to build the project:

```
msbuild :package do |msb|
  msb.properties :configuration => :Release
  msb.targets :Package
  msb.solution = "WebApplication.Site/WebApplication.Site.csproj"
end
```

then, using web deploy I want to send my package to Dev Server

```
task :deploy_devserver => [:package] do |msb|
  sh ".\\WebApplication.Site\\obj\\Release\\Package\\WebApplication.Site.deploy.cmd /y /M:http://DEVSERVER/MSDEPLOYAGENTSERVICE/MsDeploy.axd"
end
```

Everything sounds fine, except when intermittent error shows up! As IIS is locking a folder of Logs, the console say that is impossible to delete file and fire a error.

I hard tried to find a line guide of commands for automating deployment with Microsoft Web Deploy but nothing. I only found this two articles that didn't say something about `--force` or `--skip:LogsFolder`:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465322.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff356104.aspx

Just to put the icing on the cake, if change /y (yes) to /t (trial) the deploy works... (bye bye logic!)

Comment: Maybe dont delete the logs. Maybe place and app_offline.htm on the site first (in the unresearched hope it will stop the app pool) and then remove it after the deploy is complete.